# Loading Configuration POJO from org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource once using BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pojo

I'm creating spring beans dynamically (using the method described in: https://scanningpages.wordpress.com/2017/07/28/spring-dynamic-beans/)

```
@Configuration
class Conf {

    @Bean
    static BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor beanPostProcessor(final ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    ...
    }
```

However properties object can't be loaded via common way in POJO:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo") 
public class FooProperties {
```

and autowired to `beanPostProcessor` as an extra argument (simply doesn't work).

Now I have to iterate the properties like this:

```
static private FooPorperties parseProperties(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    for(PropertySource source : environment.getPropertySources()) {
        if(source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
            EnumerablePropertySource propertySource = (EnumerablePropertySource) source;
            for(String property : propertySource.getPropertyNames()) {
                if (property.startsWith("foo")) {
                    System.out.println(property);
                    // TODO set FooProperties
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My questions therefor is, is there a way to map these `PropertySource`s to my POJO without having to manually iterate those?

Answer (score 1):

I have a ugly way...

```
public static FooProperties buildProperties(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    FooProperties fooProperties = new FooProperties();

    if (environment != null) {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        new RelaxedDataBinder(fooProperties, "foo").bind(new PropertySourcesPropertyValues(propertySources));
    }

    return fooProperties;
}
```

then you can use buildProperties(configurableEnvironment) in your beanPostProcessor.

For Spring Boot version 2.+ you have to use the [refactored binding API](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#relaxed-binding).